# RTMFP communication without Flash Server

Tags: rtmfp

Is it possible to communicate with RTMFP from serverside without flash server?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you just need to communicate with the Flash player so that's not related to RTMFP and is easily accomplished.. Did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

RTMFP is a p2p communication method, but you need to have a server in order to exchange the ID of the p2p participants.